# does anyone know how I can stop GTK g_type_init() from appearing

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to use gtk_container_remove and it says I forgot to call g_type_init(), does anyone know how I can stop this from happening

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of GLib older than 2.36 (released: March 2013), then you need to heed the advice that you've been given and call the `g_type_init()` function. Newer versions of GLib call that function automatically for you.

Since you're using GTK+, though, the warning you're getting is indicative of another issue; it means you are not initializing GTK+ itself, which internally will initialize the GLib type system for you. You must initialize GTK+ by calling `gtk_init()` or `gtk_init_check()` before using any other `gtk_*` function. Usually, you call `gtk_init()` as the first thing in your `main` function body.

If you are using a version of GTK+ newer than 3.0, you should considering porting your code to the [`GtkApplication`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html) class, which will initialize GTK+ for you when you instantiate it.

For more information:

- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-init
- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html
- https://developer.gnome.org/GtkApplication/

Answer (score 0):

> Before using any GTK+ functions in your GUI applications you will have to initialize the system.

To initialize the system you will have to call `gtk_init ()`
This will initialize everything needed to operate the toolkit and parses some standard command line options.

The function `g_type_init()` is called by `gtk_init()`. 
Bottom Line : Call `gtk_init()` before using any gtk+func.

Refer [gtk_init](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-init) for more details